# Can anyone tell me what manga this is

Tags: soul-eater

[image]

It's the first full pic, and I seem to be reminded of it but I just can't recall the name of the manga or the story line

Answer (score 12):

It seems to be depicting a character from Soul Eater.

It is the main antagonist, Asura, towards the end of the manga.

From the [Soul Eater wiki page for Asura](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Asura):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

the second photo is Gajeel Redfox from Fairy Tail, which is a manga about wizards. Gajeel is
known as the metal dragon slayer who uses metal to combat his opponents!

[image: Deviant Art image]